# Declaring a class template that inherits from a different class template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Sorry for the confusing title, but I'll try to elaborate more here.  I haven't been able to find this particular problem via searching, so if I have missed it please point me to the right thread...

I have a class template dependent on one parameter which I am using as a base class:

```
template <class TVertex>
class DrawExecutorDX11
{
public:
    DrawExecutorDX11( );
    virtual ~DrawExecutorDX11( );
    void AddVertex( const TVertex& vertex );

protected:
    TGrowableVertexBufferDX11<TVertex> VertexBuffer;
};
```

What I want to do is to inherit from this class template, and at the same time add another class template parameter to the sub-class.  My attempt at the syntax would be something like this:

```
template <class TVertex, class TInstance>
class DrawInstancedExecutorDX11<TInstance> : public DrawExecutorDX11<TVertex>
{
public:
    DrawInstancedExecutorDX11( );
    virtual ~DrawInstancedExecutorDX11( );

    void AddInstance( const TInstance& data );

protected:
    TGrowableVertexBufferDX11<TInstance> InstanceBuffer;
};
```

I am hoping that this configuration would allow me to declare an instance of the subclass template like so:

```
DrawInstancedExecutorDX11<VertexStruct,InstanceStruct> myExecutor;
```

However, VS2012 doesn't even consider compiling the sub-class and indicates that it is expecting a semi-colon after class DrawInstancedExecutorDX11.  To be perfectly honest, I haven't ever tried this type of template arrangement before, so I am wondering if anyone else has done this.  If so, is there a basic syntax mistake that I am making or some other gotcha?  Thanks in advance for any help or guidance you can give!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use any angled-brackets right after the class name, you are declaring a template specialization, not the primary template.  The correct primary class template is:

```
template <class TVertex, class TInstance>
class DrawInstancedExecutorDX11 : public DrawExecutorDX11<TVertex>
{
    //...
};
```

Inside that class you can refer to template parameters `TVertex` and `TInstance`, and outside that class you can use `DrawInstancedExecutorDX11<SomeVtxType, SomeInstType>`.

Comment: Great - thanks for the answer (you answered simultaneously with @K-ballo).  That also adds some additional context to the answer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to declare a partial specialization without having declared the primary template definition. Before the declaration of `DrawInstancedExecutorDX11<TInstance>` you would need

```
template <class TVertex, class TInstance>
class DrawInstancedExecutorDX11;
```

That should get ride of your first compiler error, but fail afterwards. I'm not sure what you are actually trying to accomplish with this. It seems that you simply need:

```
template <class TVertex, class TInstance>
class DrawInstancedExecutorDX11 : public DrawExecutorDX11<TVertex>
{ ... };
```

Comment: I am trying to define the base class that provides one set of operations (using the 'VertexBuffer' member), and then specializing a portion of that functionality with another set of operations (using the 'InstanceBuffer' member).  The only difference to ordinary inheritance is that the types of those two member variables are generic.

Comment: @Jason Zink: Then don't you just want `template <class TVertex, class TInstance> class DrawInstancedExecutorDX11 : public DrawExecutorDX11<TVertex>` ?

Comment: Yes!  That was the issue - I shouldn't have added the template arguments to the subclass declaration.  Thanks for the help - I knew it would be some small syntax error!  How can I give you credit for the answer?

Comment: @Jason Zink: You should see an empty check mark next to my answer